# Typescript compile file

Tags: javascript, typescript

i compile my class:

```
export class Test implements baseTest
```

Compile file have first string:

```
define(Object, ......,);
```

How i can compile withor define only like this:

```
var Test = (function(){..})();
```

Comment: I believe that is defined by the `compilerOptions.module` property of your tsconfig.json file. It compiles your modules differently based on which option you have selected. Try setting it to "CommonJS". [Docs here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: It may also be in conjunction with the `compilerOptions.target` property as well. Try targeting "ES5". You may have to play around with different combinations.

Comment: target only for class || function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `export` keyword. You're trying to make a module when it seems you want global code.